# navigation related issue in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am doing nevigation in one screen (i.e firstScreen) to next screen (i.e. secondFile).  My code is in firstFile.m  is :

```
- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender
{

secondFile* dest = [[secondFile alloc] initWithNibName:@" secondFile" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dest animated:YES];


NSString* uname = txtUserName.text;
NSLog(@"usr name is : %@",uname);

}
```

firstScreen.h

```
<UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface nevigationViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnNevigation;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUserName;
- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

Problem is that log is printed but navigation is not perform. please, can u tell me what is wrong in above code.

Comment: is your navigation controller properly initialized?

Comment: pls check wheter ur navigation is initialize or not with : NSLog(@"%d",self.navigationController);

Comment: initWithNibName:@" secondFile"  <-- See the space.

Comment: why there is space before initWithNibName:@" secondFile", replace by @"secondFile"

Comment: i remove comment but still get same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the space from **@" secondFile"** in 
`secondFile* dest = [[secondFile alloc] initWithNibName:@" secondFile" bundle:nil];`

If the issue still survives and if you don't require navigationController at all then just simply use :

```
  secondFile *nextView = [[secondFile alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondFile" bundle:nil];
  [self presentModalViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender
{

secondFile* dest = [[secondFile alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondFile" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dest animated:YES];


NSString* uname = txtUserName.text;
NSLog(@"usr name is : %@",uname);

}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: try presentModalViewController

Comment: Accept answer as this helps others to refer